# Setting default value for a datetime-local input field in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, datetime-local

I would like to set the `value` of an `input:datetime-local` field in **Blade** with data from the database but it only shows a blank placeholder values.

Below is my attempt which is not working:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" value="{{ date('d/m/YH:i', strtotime($slider->run_to)) }}">
```

In my research, I have found out that the field needs `value` in this format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM` or like in my case `d/m/YTH:i` where `T` is a string literal.

My problem is I am not able to find a way to do this in **Laravel-Blade** with dynamic data.

Is there any way to achieve it? If not then what alternatives are there for displaying date time in an input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of [datetime-local value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#value) format isn't similar to what we see on the browser by default.

> ... **the displayed date and time formats differ from the actual value**; the displayed date and time are formatted according to the user's locale as reported by their operating system, whereas the date/time value is always formatted **YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm**.

---

I'll replace your `$slider->run_to` with the valid `datetime` `'2022-03-17 23:59:26'` to provide my solution

```html
<input type="datetime-local" value="{{ substr(date('c', strtotime('2022-03-17 23:59:26')), 0, 16) }}">
```

1. I used to [format character](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#:%7E:text=c,ISO%208601%20date) `c` that stands for **ISO 8601 date** which outputs `'2022-03-17T23:59:26+01:00'`.
2. I did cutout **the seconds** and **the UTC offset** `':26+01:00'`

- Note that allowing the seconds with `substr` `$length` of `19` wouldn't break the element.

[image]

[image]

Demo: https://3v4l.org/aMpMN

---

Another alternative solution that includes **seconds**:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" value="{{ str_replace(' ', 'T', '2022-03-17 23:59:26') }}">
```

[image]

Demo: https://3v4l.org/710EN

Comment: The second alternative worked while the first did not, I'm researching on the reason why and will update my comment to help anyone who may have the same problem in future

Comment: @TheOnlySmartBoy Show me the value of `$slider->run_to` and `date('c', strtotime($slider->run_to))`